# HTML performance turning

Tags: html

i want to ask did **html** structure effect the performance of page loading?

But im not asking about the request of external js/css, but html layout structure

For example using div or table...something like that

Did **html** structure effect the performance of page loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, though it's negligible relatively to the CSS and JavaScript performance issues caused by bad HTML structure.

Comment: how about the inline js or css position? and even layout structure

Comment: inline js or css positions are not part of the HTML. `<style>` and `<script>` tags are effectively not rendered. Rather, I'm talking about unused elements and table layouts. Also deep nesting of elements is also to be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some things to speed up your page depending on your HTML part.

First avoid use Tables as they need more time to be rendered on Web Browsers.
If posible minimize your HTML by removing white spaces.
Create beter use of HTML element. In exmplate consider that:

```
<div>
    <span class="red">Hello red people !</span>
</div>

<div class="red">
    Hello red people !
</div>
```

The second part is more optimal.

At the time I don't know any other speed optimization that you can do on your HTML

Comment: so, what you mean is try to minimize html tag, and use css to style the layout?